# I cant update mysql data base on server using android

Tags: php, android, mysql

public class personal extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String insertUrl= "http://some.url/insert.php";
RequestQueue queue;
String flnr, ankunft,date,time, plz, addr,direction,name,email,telefon,perosnen,koffer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal);
    back();
    order();
}
public  void order (){
    Button orderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order_button);
    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getValues();
            sendToDataBase();
            Intent in = new Intent(personal.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });


}
public  void sendToDataBase(){

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("datum",date);
            parameters.put("zeit",time);
            parameters.put("plz",plz);
            parameters.put("adresse",addr);
            parameters.put("flugnummer",flnr);
            parameters.put("ankunft",ankunft);
            parameters.put("name",name);
            parameters.put("email",email);
            parameters.put("telefon",telefon);
            parameters.put("personen",perosnen);
            parameters.put("koffer",koffer);

            return parameters;
        }
    };
    queue.add(request);
}

public void getValues (){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    date = extras.getString("Datum");
    time = extras.getString("Zeit");
    plz = extras.getString("PLZ");
    addr = extras.getString("Adresse");
    direction = extras.getString("Richtung");
    flnr = extras.getString("Flugnummer");
    ankunft = extras.getString("Ankunft");
    EditText editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    EditText editEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
    EditText editTelefon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_phone);
    EditText editPer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_pers);
    EditText editKoffer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_lugage);
    name = editName.getText().toString();
    email = editEmail.getText().toString();
    telefon = editTelefon.getText().toString();
    perosnen = editPer.getText().toString();
    koffer = editKoffer.getText().toString();

}

public void  back(){
    Button backButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(personal.this,order.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Im tring to update a mysql database, and this is the code i wrote but i simply wont update the database u don't know why it wont work i can't find the problem.

Comment: If I may say, you should not post your endpoint url (sorry for the blank record). I will edit

Comment: Thanks but do you know what the problem is ? :D

Comment: In `System.out.println(response.toString());` is shown any error? If not, i suggest you to write in file what is received by $_POST in your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem might be related to server
can you fill

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
    VolleyLog.d("ERRORVOLLEY", "Error is: " + error.getMessage());
```

method so that we can see what the response is if any error occurs.

p.s. really wanted to comment this but rep didn't allow.

Comment: how should i fill it ?